# Is there a way to get iOS System alarm notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I'm coding a timer app, and I've noticed a major drawback: while I can make the alarm send the user a notification when the timer is done, it can only send notifications, while the built-in Clock app triggers a fullscreen alert no matter what screen you are on, ensuring the user sees the end of the timer. Is there any way to integrate my app with iOS to allow this fullscreen alert functionality? I send a notification when the alarm finishes - is there a specific type of notification that I need to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You have to stay within the confines of your app. The iOS Clock app has special privileges because...well, it's made by Apple.

Is the notification not enough? I would think that would alert the user adequately.